# How to deploy mutiple SSIS packages to SQL Server at one time?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have 200 SSIS packages and I want to deploy all these packages to SQL Server at one time. Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deploy them using `DTUtil` in batch file, and kick off each deploy simultaneously:

```
@start /b cmd /c DTUTIL /FILE package1.dtsx /COPY SQL;package1  /DESTSERVER "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"
@start /b cmd /c DTUTIL /FILE package2.dtsx /COPY SQL;package2  /DESTSERVER "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"
@start /b cmd /c DTUTIL /FILE package3.dtsx /COPY SQL;package3  /DESTSERVER "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"
@start /b cmd /c DTUTIL /FILE package4.dtsx /COPY SQL;package4  /DESTSERVER "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"
```

I'm sure you could get clever and loop through each `dtsx` file in the current directory... something like this:

```
for %%f in (*.dtsx) do (
    echo Importing %%~nf
    start /b cmd /c DTUTIL /FILE %%~nf.dtsx /COPY SQL;%%~nf /DESTSERVER "SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME"
)
```